# Column is constrained to be unique. Value is already present

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, dataadapter

When I hit the following line of code I get this error

```
Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable)
```

The Error is

"Column 'SubscriberID, PublisherID' is constrained to be unique.  Value 'NAV, PATN' is already present."

Here is the full code

```
Public Overridable Overloads Function GetData() As MYDAL.MYDataTable
    Me.Adapter.SelectCommand = Me.CommandCollection(0)
    Dim dataTable As MYDAL.MYTable = New MYDAL.MYDataTable()
    Try
        Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Return dataTable
End Function
```

I don't understand where the above error is coming from. I checked the table in the database and it has multiple rows with NAV, PATN values. But there is no constraint physically on those 2 columns on the table itself.

There is no constraint in .net code .. not that I have discovered so I don't know where the following error is coming from. Or how could I debug further?

"Column 'SubscriberID, PublisherID' is constrained to be unique.  Value 'NAV, PATN' is already present."

Here is the select statement it tries to execute

```
SELECT SC.ActiveFlag
, SC.SubscriberID
, SC.PublisherID
, SC.PublicationGroupID
, SC.ArticleID
, SC.TerminateFlag
, SC.CirculationDaysBeforeArchive
, SC.CirculationRetentionDays
, SC.LastRetentionDate
, SC.LastArchiveDate
, SC.LastRetentionDate
, SC.LastArchiveDate
, S.SubscriberName
FROM dbo.Subscription SC
JOIN dbo.Subscriber S ON SC.SubscriberID = S.SubscriberID
ORDER BY S.SubscriberName
```

Here are all the constraints in the databsae on this table

Name                                                                                                                             Owner                                                                                                                            Type                            Created_datetime

---

Subscription                                                                                                                     dbo                                                                                                                              user table                      2007-09-14 23:38:56.513

Column_name                                                                                                                      Type                                                                                                                             Computed                            Length      Prec  Scale Nullable                            TrimTrailingBlanks                  FixedLenNullInSource                Collation

---

ActiveFlag                                                                                                                       typYesNo                                                                                                                         no                                  1                       no                                  (n/a)                               (n/a)                               NULL
SubscriberID                                                                                                                     typSubscriberID                                                                                                                  no                                  4                       no                                  no                                  no                                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
PublisherID                                                                                                                      typPublisherID                                                                                                                   no                                  4                       no                                  no                                  no                                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
PublicationGroupID                                                                                                               typPublicationGrpID                                                                                                              no                                  6                       no                                  no                                  no                                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
CirculationRetentionDays                                                                                                         smallint                                                                                                                         no                                  2           5     0     no                                  (n/a)                               (n/a)                               NULL
ArticleID                                                                                                                        typArticleID                                                                                                                     no                                  6                       no                                  no                                  no                                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
TerminateFlag                                                                                                                    typYesNo                                                                                                                         no                                  1                       no                                  (n/a)                               (n/a)                               NULL
CirculationDaysBeforeArchive                                                                                                     smallint                                                                                                                         no                                  2           5     0     no                                  (n/a)                               (n/a)                               NULL
LastRetentionDate                                                                                                                datetime                                                                                                                         no                                  8                       yes                                 (n/a)                               (n/a)                               NULL
LastArchiveDate                                                                                                                  datetime                                                                                                                         no                                  8                       yes                                 (n/a)                               (n/a)                               NULL

Identity                                                                                                                         Seed                                    Increment                               Not For Replication

---

No identity column defined.                                                                                                      NULL                                    NULL                                    NULL

### RowGuidCol

No rowguidcol column defined.

### Data_located_on_filegroup

PRIMARY

index_name                                                                                                                       index_description                                                                                                                                                                                                  index_keys

---

fkPubArticleID                                                                                                                   nonclustered located on PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                    PublisherID, PublicationGroupID, ArticleID
fkSubscriptionID                                                                                                                 nonclustered located on PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                    SubscriberID
pkSubscription                                                                                                                   clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                  SubscriberID, PublisherID, PublicationGroupID, ArticleID

constraint_type                                                                                                                                    constraint_name                                                                                                                  delete_action update_action status_enabled status_for_replication constraint_keys

---

DEFAULT on column ActiveFlag                                                                                                                       DefOne130                                                                                                                        (n/a)         (n/a)         (n/a)          (n/a)                  (1)
PRIMARY KEY (clustered)                                                                                                                            pkSubscription                                                                                                                   (n/a)         (n/a)         (n/a)          (n/a)                  SubscriberID, PublisherID, PublicationGroupID, ArticleID
FOREIGN KEY                                                                                                                                        Publication_Subscription                                                                                                         No Action     No Action     Enabled        Is_For_Replication     PublisherID, PublicationGroupID, ArticleID
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      REFERENCES DataDistribution_DEV.dbo.Publication (PublisherID, PublicationGroupID, ArticleID)
FOREIGN KEY                                                                                                                                        Subscriber_Subscription                                                                                                          No Action     No Action     Enabled        Is_For_Replication     SubscriberID
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      REFERENCES DataDistribution_DEV.dbo.Subscriber (SubscriberID)

### Table is referenced by foreign key

DataDistribution_DEV.dbo.Circulation: Subscription_Circulation
DataDistribution_DEV.dbo.CirculationStatusChange: Subscription_CircStatusChange
DataDistribution_DEV.dbo.TaskSubscription: Subscription_NotifSubscription

No views with schema binding reference table 'Subscription'.

Comment: check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3bxwk8b.aspx
and this
http://etutorials.org/Programming/ado+net/Part+I+ADO.NET+Tutorial/Chapter+7.+DataTables/7.3+Constraints/

Comment: The constraint might not be in your database but in the typed dataset / datatable that was generated from your xsd file ... to find out more about what actually caused the problem you could catch the System.Data.ConstraintException ... or inspect datatable.GetErrors() (C#) ...

Comment: This happened to me upon simply loading a DataTable with the values from a small SqlServer table with a column of type timestamp (no constraints, no primary key).  It gave this error for some wild reason.  I was just testing something so I was able to remove the timestamp column.  Very strange.